# Ошибка после переноса проекта на laravel 7.12 на хостинг

Tags: laravel

Перенес проект laravel 7.12 на хостинг.
При входе появляется сообщение: File not found.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Куда копать?

Comment: Какая конкретно ошибка? Что за не найденный файл? Пробовали composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Composer dump-autoload. Это текст ошибки на странице при входе. Начал искать, комментируя строки в /public/index.php . Ошибка возникает в index.php при подключении $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

Comment: Всё ли вы перенесли на хостинг? Встал ли вендор? Так как то что вы описываете более похоже на то что не встали пакеты... index.php дефолтный если не понимаете как работает трогать не стоит... Сейчас вы просто отключили подгрузку ядра, по этому ошибка ушла

Comment: Я это понимаю, просто нужно было найти откуда приходит ошибка. Сейчас перенес проект на хостинг, используя гит. Ошибка та же

Comment: Пробовали вендор удалить и заново заинсталить проект?